# Twig theme variables

Tags: 8, theming

I am working on creating a theme from scratch for Drupal 8 and I am 90% of the way there.  I do have a question on how to access variables in the

```
{{ dump() | raw }}
```

I have created a page.html.twig and the {{ page.BLOCKNAME }} is working great.  But when I try to place {{ title }}, or any variations, I get NULL or nothing at all.

I can see the title in the dump(), but it has ["string":protected]=> so I am not able to access. I was able to create a new block region and move the title there, but the title will not be in the same place from page to page.  I would also like to access the content type, node ID, and node url, with some other custom fields I created, but I can't seem to get to those either.

In summary, how do I use the dump() and actually get to the variables that are presented?

Comment: Simple - title is now a block and not a twig template variable anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna see all variables available in your twig template file in Drupal 8 use `{{ kint(_context) }}`. Don't forget, you must enable kint in devel module settings.

Comment: No need to use `kint` when we have a perfectly valid `dump` out of the box

Answer (score 1):

In the page template you shouldn't be printing blocks directly. Blocks should be always printed inside a regions. More information about how to add your custom region can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2469113).

If you are printing an already existing region the syntax for that is:

```
{{ page.region_name }}
```